# System.Web.HttpInputStream instead of the correct sharepoint pic library URL when storing the image url in the database

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Working solution. Thank you everyone. Hope this helps. This involves getting the sharepoint absolute URL to store in a database column, and storing the picture in a sharepoint pic library

Thanks
Nicolas

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace UploadDataImage.UploadImage
{
    public partial class UploadImageUserControl : UserControl
    {
        string absURL = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = SP-DEV-MACHINE; Initial Catalog=The_Performance; Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Project_ID from Test1", con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Project_ID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void Btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SPSite site = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    Stream StreamImage = null;
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        StreamImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        SPList pics = web.Lists["picture"];
                        SPListItem li = pics.RootFolder.Files.Add(FileUpload1.FileName, StreamImage).GetListItem();

                        absURL = li.Web.Url +"/"+ li.Url;
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Newsss values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + absURL + "' )", con);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        con.Close();
                        Label7.Visible = true;
                        Label7.Text = "success";
                        TextBox1.Text = "";
                        TextBox2.Text = "";
                        TextBox3.Text = "";
                        TextBox4.Text = "";
                        TextBox5.Text = "";
                        TextBox6.Text = "";
                        TextBox7.Text = "";
                        TextBox8.Text = "";
                        TextBox9.Text = "";
                        TextBox10.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you already done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Sharepoint URL in the database, you should add it to the List first, as you are doing, then you can get the URL to put in the database. You can do something like:

```
SPListItem li = pics.RootFolder.Files.Add(FileUpload1.FileName, StreamImage).GetListItem();
string absURL = li["EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();
```

This will give you the full path to the file in `absURL` which you can insert into your table.

Comment: Hi mafafu: thanks for your response, however, I am getting the following error while trying to build.Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). this is for li["EncodedAbsUrl"]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `ToString()` above. I edited the answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot and it finally works. The modifications that I did were as follows:string absURL = string.Empty;
 StreamImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        SPList pics = web.Lists["picture"];
                        SPListItem li = pics.RootFolder.Files.Add(FileUpload1.FileName, StreamImage).GetListItem();
                      
                      
                         absURL = li.Web.Url +"/"+ li.Url;

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Newsss values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + absURL + "' )", con);

Comment: I'm glad this helped. You can edit your answer to include all that code of how you made it work if you want in case someone else needs it (and it would be more readable in the body). And if this answer helped you can Accept this answer.

Comment: Now I need help in saving a selected value(project_ID /test1 table) from dropdown list to the (Business_Unit /Newsss table) column in the database, any help would be appreciated. I am now working on this. I haven't created a column by the name of Business_Unit yet in the Newsss table, since I am not sure whether there would be a syntax error with number of columns in the code not matching with the number of columns in database. Please help

Comment: You should probably post this as a new question with all the relevant detail and appropriate tags, being as specific as you can. Adding the correct tags will help make your question visible to other users who can help.

Comment: Fixed it: only change was: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Newsss values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + absURL + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')", con);